# how do you install perception_pcl in melodic in ubuntu?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualize pcd files and have been following this [thread here](https://answers.ros.org/question/27483/how-to-visualize-pcd-file/) to do it however I am not able to find the perception_pcl command in the rosrun meta commands.

Am I missing something, the documentation for it does not give me much to go on http://wiki.ros.org/perception_pcl

I have already tried sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-perception-pcl but it still does not show up

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342602/how-do-you-install-perception_pcl-in-melodic-in-ubuntu?/) by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-27**:
Have you installed `pcl-tools` ? From your thread it seems that you need this and then visualize your pointcloud using the command `pcl_viewer FILENAME`.

**Comment by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on 2020-01-27**:
Hey Delb, they were not installed. Where would I have gone to find what needed to be installed? i am testing this now to see if it works

**Comment by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on 2020-01-27**:
@Delb that did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: `pcd_viewer` has not been part of `perception_pcl` since at least Hydro.

The tool is now called `pcl_viewer` and is part of the (stand-alone) PCL package: `pcl-tools` (at least on Debian/Ubuntu). It's not part of ROS.

See #q80836. The OP there answers his own question and states something similar.

> Where in the ros.org would i have needed to go to find this bit of info?

I'm not sure this is a "ROS thing".

Please note that PCL is a stand-alone library. It's not a piece of ROS. There are packages that let you use it with ROS, but it's completely stand-alone, and it's development also happens outside of the ROS community.

The Q&A you linked is 8 years old. PCL has moved on, answers get stale. The wiki page you linked also makes no mention of the tool. Nor do any of the other pages about PCL-related packages (such as [pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros)).

`perception_pcl` is actually a metapackage that facilitates installation of all ROS PCL wrapping packages. See the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/perception_pcl). It being a metapackage also explains why there isn't much content: it doesn't contain any nodes, messages or other ROS-related infrastructure.

---

Edit 2: I've updated the `pcl_perception` wiki page ([diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/perception_pcl?action=diff&rev2=18&rev1=16)) to point readers to `pcl_ros` and make it clear that package is just a metapackage. Not something that contains any code, libraries or nodes.

---

Original answer:

you're not giving us much information.

> I have already tried sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-perception-pcl but it still does not show up

Did the package install? Did you get any errors? Something else? What is "it" here?

What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep perception-pcl`?

After `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`, what is the output of `rospack find perception_pcl`?

> I am trying to visualize pcd files and have been following this thread here to do it however I am not able to find the perception_pcl command [..]

Please note: `pcd_viewer` would be the tool. `pcl_perception` is the package (which hosts the tool).

You cannot execute `pcl_perception`. Only `pcd_viewer`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on 2020-01-27**:
Sorry im not sure how much or how little information is required here. I assume by your reply that the package i installed is the right one. The package did install and there was no problems that i was able to see.

Here is the output of your request

```
dpkg -l | grep perception-pcl
ii  ros-melodic-perception-pcl                   1.7.0-2bionic.20191211.062537                   amd64        PCL (Point Cloud Library) ROS interface stack.
metrolla@metrolla-ThinkPad-11e:~/catkin_ws$ source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash 
metrolla@metrolla-ThinkPad-11e:~/catkin_ws$ rospack find perception_pcl
[rospack] Error: package 'perception_pcl' not found
metrolla@metrolla-ThinkPad-11e:~/catkin_ws$
```

The [thread i was looking at](https://answers.ros.org/question/27483/how-to-visualize-pcd-file/) showed the following command. is this no longer correct?

```
rosrun perception_pcl pcd_viewer <filename>
```

**Comment by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on 2020-01-27**:
@Delb pointed out that `pcl-tools` was required for me to use pcl_viewer. this was the missing component. How would I have known what needed to be installed given this case? Where in the ros.org would i have needed to go to find this bit of info?

**Comment by [AdamS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51217/adams/) on 2020-01-27**:
thanks for the insight. I am rather new to working with LiDAR but jumping headfirst into the deepend of ROS is a lot to digest. I actually thought it was part of ROS. Thank you for clarifying this.